# Accessing component properties from jQuery or other events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, vis.js

I'm trying to use `vis.js` (or jQuery) click events in an Angular2 component. I have my graph displaying just fine, and I can successfully catch click events.

However, within the context of click events, I loose my references to my component's properties. For example, `this.visData` is `undefined` from within the event:

```
export class GraphContainerComponent implements OnInit {
    private visData: {};
    private options: {} = {};
    private network: any;
    @ViewChild('graphContainer') graphContainer;

    ngOnInit() {
        // populates this.visData
        // this.visData = { nodes, edges }
        this.makeGraph();
    }

    makeGraph() {
        // no problem creating and displaying my graph, everything works
        this.network = new vis.Network(this.graphContainer.nativeElement, this.visData, this.options);

        // click event
        this.network.on("selectNode", function (params) {
            console.log(this.visData); // logs "undefined"
        }

        $('a').on('click', function() {
            console.log(this.visData); // "undefined" as well
        });
    }
}
```

I understand why this is normal behavior, and *I know mixing Angular2 and jQuery or some other DOM-manipulating library is not recommended practice*, but sometimes it's all you got.

**What's the best way to maintain a reference to my component's properties from within these events?**

Crucially, there are dozens of these components on my page, so I don't think some kind of global storage is the way to go.

Comment: Just use lambdas `() => {}` instead of `function () {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use ***arrow function (()=>)*** as shown below,

```
this.network.on("selectNode", (params)=> {  //<----this should work.
        console.log(this.visData); // logs "undefined"
    }

$('a').on('click', ()=> {                   //<----this should work.
            console.log(this.visData); // "undefined" as well
});
```